# Screen mirroring option not found: Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dell, projector

I am using a Dell XPS13 9360 machine and running Ubuntu 21.10. I want to connect a projector (ViewSonic M1 mini) but in settings I don't have any option to mirror my screen. What is the problem and how do I fix this?

- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4
- Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.1, 256 bits)

Settings → Screen Display:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have an Intel graphics card. Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02). Do I need to install Nvidia drivers?

$ prime-select query
intel

Comment: You're correct apparently. Most XPS I know have Intel + Nvidia. Now, the problem is with the Intel graphics NOT having the correct driver in use (why, I have no idea). It should report as Intel HD Graphics XXX, not "llvmpipe" which is software rendering in absence of proper drivers and - importantly - doesn't support external video outputs.

Comment: Have you by any chance installed Ubuntu in Legacy ("BIOS"/CSM) mode? That could explain it...

Comment: @ChanganAuto No pretty sure I am using UEFI. I can find /sys/firmware/efi

Comment: Try (re-)installing `xserver-xorg-video-intel`

Comment: @ChanganAuto done, no luck

Comment: What was the message exactly?

Comment: Sorry I rebooted so can't paste the message. It was something like 1 to install 0 to upgrade etc etc and it installed. Evidently I did not have it installed previously.

Comment: And it didn't change the graphics in settings > about?

Comment: Aha! it has changed to Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2). But I still don't see any additional settings in Screen Display (attached image in the question)

Comment: Reboot and try again. Unplug, plug the HDMI cable.